# Evaluating String from configuration file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a string in my configuration file say something like

```
 FirstParam|MyFile`date +"%Y%m%d"`.xml
```

My Script reads this line and splits values by pipe (e.g. "|") I want to convert second part i.e. MyFile`date +"%Y%m%d"`.xml  to MyFile20141215.xml and pass it to another method. What is the best possible way for achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The one quick and dirty I would use is (supposing a.txt is your file)

```
TodayFileName=`cut -d\| -f2 a.txt`
eval TodayFileName=$TodayFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are concerned with security, you want to avoid evaluating 'external' commands.
When the config file is just as secure as your script, eval is fine.
When the config file can be changed by people with less rights, consider parsing the
string with special fields:

```
$-> cat myfile
FirstParam|MyFileSED_YYYYMMDD.xml

$-> cat myParser
cat myfile | while IFS=\|; read firstfield secondfield; do
        echo Split into ${firstfield} en ${secondfield}
        echo "callingOtherMethodWith $(echo ${secondfield} |
           sed 's/SED_YYYYMMDD/'$(date +"%Y%m%d")'/')"
done
```